# Why did my code stop working?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

When I entered docmd. In my code it worked, until I closed it then it stopped working here is my code .

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If (Txtusername = "123" And txtpassword = 123) Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Kappa", View:=acNormal, DataMode:=acFormPropertySettings, windowMode:=acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Login or Password"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code should be integrated as **text** in the question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @fvu edited to include the code

Comment: What does 'stopped working' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Have you step debugged?

Comment: @June7 when i click on the button a specify it closes the form that is open not go to the form i specify –

Comment: @June7 when i entered that code it did nothing

Comment: @June7 want a video?

Comment: You tried the code in my answer? Should have put comment under the answer. I tested your code and get the behavior I describe. My code works properly. I have never used that OpenForm syntax but don't see anything wrong with it. I would use simply `DoCmd.OpenForm "Kappa"` in this case because the other arguments are just using defaults.

Comment: @June7 my fault I put the same form for close and open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the form you call is opening then immediately closing (do you see it 'flash') because the opening form gets focus and the DoCmd.Close is acting on form that has focus. The calling form remains open. Specify the form to close.

`DoCmd.Close acForm, "form name", acSaveNo`

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.Close` closes the object currently having the focus. This is the Form opened in the previous line. I assume that you want to close the Form running this code. So, write:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```